# How to use external variables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in SQL which goes like this ..

```
create PROCEDURE procedure_name
( 
@Name varchar, 
@Price int 
)

AS 
BEGIN

select * from table
where Name=@Name AND Price=@Price

END
```

When I call the stored procedure with values - John and 14228.. I get an empty table back. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

When I run the following snippet below, I get an output with rows.

```
 select * 
FROM table 
WHERE Name = 'John' AND price = '14228';
```

Any help will be appreciated! thanks

Comment: @dasblinkenlight check edit above.. The datatable I receive after calling the sp is empty with no rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Name` variable needs to have a size specified.  When you specify [`varchar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) without a size SQL Server interprets that as `varchar(1)`.  So only the first character of the parameter you pass to the stored procedure is used.

The `@Name` should have the same size as the size of the `Name` column.  For exampe:

```
create PROCEDURE procedure_name
( 
  @Name varchar(30), 
  @Price int 
)
...
```